# Hide rows only for certain columns

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet with tables that I can be hidden/revealed by the user for readability.  I want to put a long summary table along the side of the same worksheet, and I don't want that summary table to get hidden when the other tables are hidden.

So is there a way I can leave some columns with unhidden rows while other columns have hidden rows, or even a way I can freeze a section that can be viewed next to the rest of the sheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm quite sure that you can't hide cells in specific rows only in some columns and not in others.  You can freeze left and top columns and rows in the view ribbon, but if you hide rows, they'll still be hidden in the frozen parts.

If you want something to show on the left side even when rows are hidden, it would have to be something that can "float" above the cells, like some kind of form (which would probably be modal), or a graphic that does not move or size with cells.

You might be able to create a PNG of a range on the fly, and then "Paste" it into A1, so that it sits to the left of your data, even though you have hidden cells.  Maybe :)

Comment: Excellent idea to copy the table and paste it as a photo!